# Problem with building kivy andrioid app using buildozer, pyodbc says file sql.h is missing

Tags: python, kivy, pyodbc, buildozer, kivymd

I am trying to deploy my kivy app with a pyodbc requirement to Android with Buildozer running on a linux virtual machine.
Problem strikes when I try to build my app where it said that the "sql.h" is missing for pyodbc module.
I know from more searching that pyodbc isn't natively supported on linux, thereby how can I build my app with the pyodbc module ?

I have tried with installing unixodbc-dev, but that still hasn't fixed my problem/
I have also looked for more answers online but still, it fails.
Your help will be much appreciated, thankss

Comment: The module ```pyodbc``` includes C source files and there is no p4a ```recipe``` for this module. Without the recipe this would not compile in buildozer.

Comment: thanks for responding, I'm quite new to this sort of things, so can I make the recipe within buildozer or in pycharm ?

Comment: You can look into link: https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes. But creating custom recipes specially Cython recipes is not trivial.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, gonna try to make my own I guess

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem too. i use ubuntu for convert kivy to apk. i could not find any answer to be satistied. while trying some things i found a code from here https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install

it says you should setup someting for ubuntu on ubuntu command panel;

1-) sudo apt install python3-pip python3-dev unixodbc-dev

2-) pip3 install --user pyodbc

i had run theese codes and then tried to packing it worked for me.